# Python to Plot Graphics and Output Vector XY Pairs

Tags: python, graphics, vector, python-module

I need to draw some vector graphics, which is new for me.

Looking for some recommendations for Python modules that can plot vector shapes and output them into a series of XY moves. The shapes will generally be circles and lines and other simple shapes, but will have algorithmic modifiers to thicken, wiggle, or "grunge up" the lines.

I saw a few of the plot libraries (MathGL, matplotlib, pyplot), which all seem to create graphics. Ultimately, I want it to break down the output into a series of XY instructions consisting of a lot of little straight lines.

(I am using Python to output instructions to a digital-to-analog converter controlling the XY movements of a laser.)

Please forgive the blundering of my question. I'll update the question as I am able to formulate it better.

EDIT: On the other hand, maybe this is so simple for those who are move handy with the Maths maybe a PyModule is overkill.  Open to suggestions for cutting up curves into lines.

EDIT2: In the end, I ended up doing my own calculations, but using pyglet to do the vector graphic output.

Comment: An answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654582/convert-a-svg-image-to-multiple-vector-line-segments-using-python

Comment: This definitely helps chop up the results. But how about a Python module for creating the original SVG?

Comment: pysvg? or as svg is xml .. you could write your own.  Use sax get a line, draw a line, get a curve draw a bunch of lines?  

Or take a look at pycairo?  or even postscript (though that's a bit dated).

Is there software that exists for this particular application already? http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Simple_LinuxCNC_G-Code_Generators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pyglet to do the vector graphic output, and doing my own calculations for drawing circles and lines with the help of cubicSpline code from NYU.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# core modules
from itertools import chain

# installed modules
import pyglet
import numpy

# local modules
import config

# constants
CURVE_SEGS = config.curve_segments  # number of line segs in a curve

# bezier curves courtesy of NYU

def fac( k ):
    '''
    Returns k!.
    '''

    if k == 0: return 1
    else: return reduce(lambda i,j : i*j, range(1,k+1))

def binom( n, k ):
    '''
    Returns n choose k.
    '''

    if k < 0 or k > n: return 0

    return fac( n ) / ( fac( k ) * fac( n - k ) )

def B( P, t ):
    '''
    Evaluates the bezier curve of degree len(P) - 1, using control points 'P',
    at parameter value 't' in [0,1].
    '''
    n = len( P ) - 1
    assert n > 0

    from numpy import zeros
    result = zeros( len( P[0] ) )
    for i in xrange( n + 1 ):
        result += binom( n, i ) * P[i] * (1 - t)**(n-i) * t**i

    return result

def B_n( P, n, t ):
    '''
    Evaluates the bezier curve of degree 'n', using control points 'P',
    at parameter value 't' in [0,1].
    '''

    ## clamp t to the range [0,1]
    t = min( 1., max( 0., t ) )

    num_segments = 1 + (len( P ) - (n+1) + n-1) // n
    assert num_segments > 0
    from math import floor
    segment_offset = min( int( floor( t * num_segments ) ), num_segments-1 )

    P_offset = segment_offset * n

    return B( P[ P_offset : P_offset + n+1 ], ( t - segment_offset/float(num_segments) ) * num_segments )

def Bezier_Curve( P ):
    '''
    Returns a function object that can be called with parameters between 0 and 1
    to evaluate the Bezier Curve with control points 'P' and degree len(P)-1.
    '''
    return lambda t: B( P, t )

def Bezier_Curve_n( P, n ):
    '''
    Returns a function object that can be called with parameters between 0 and 1
    to evaluate the Bezier Curve strip with control points 'P' and degree n.
    '''
    return lambda t: B_n( P, n, t )

def cubicSpline(p0, p1, p2, p3, nSteps):
    """Returns a list of line segments and an index to make the full curve.

    Cubics are defined as a start point (p0) and end point (p3) and
    control points (p1 & p2) and a parameter t that goes from 0.0 to 1.0.
    """
    points = numpy.array([p0, p1, p2, p3])
    bez = bezier.Bezier_Curve( points )
    lineSegments = []
    for val in numpy.linspace( 0, 1, nSteps ):
        #print '%s: %s' % (val, bez( val ))
        # the definition of the spline means the parameter t goes
        # from 0.0 to 1.0
        (x,y) = bez(val)
        lineSegments.append((int(x),int(y)))
    #lineSegments.append(p2)
    cubicIndex = [0] + [int(x * 0.5) for x in range(2, (nSteps-1)*2)] + [nSteps-1]
    #print "lineSegments = ",lineSegments
    #print "cubicIndex = ",cubicIndex
    return (lineSegments,cubicIndex)


# graphic primatives

class GraphicObject(object):

    """Basic graphic object primative"""

    def __init__(self, field, points, index, color):
        """Graphic object constructor.

            Args:
                arcpoints - list of points that define the graphic object
                arcindex - list of indicies to arcpoints
                color - list of colors of each arc
        """
        self.m_field = field
        self.m_arcpoints = points
        self.m_arcindex = index
        self.m_color = color
        # each arc is broken down into a list of points and indecies
        # these are gathered into lists of lists
        # TODO: possibly these could be melded into single dim lists
        self.m_points = []
        self.m_index = []

class Circle(GraphicObject):

    """Define circle object."""

    def __init__(self, field, p, r, color,solid=False):
        """Circle constructor.

        Args:
            p - center point
            r - radius of circle
            c - color
        """
        self.m_center = p
        self.m_radius = r
        self.m_solid = solid
        k = 0.5522847498307935  # 4/3 (sqrt(2)-1)
        kr = int(r*k)
        (x,y)=p
        arcpoints=[(x+r,y),(x+r,y+kr), (x+kr,y+r), (x,y+r),
                           (x-kr,y+r), (x-r,y+kr), (x-r,y),
                           (x-r,y-kr), (x-kr,y-r), (x,y-r),
                            (x+kr,y-r), (x+r,y-kr)]
        arcindex=[(0, 1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 7, 8, 9), (9, 10, 11, 0)]
        GraphicObject.__init__(self,field,arcpoints,arcindex,color)

    def render(self):
        # e.g., self.m_arcpoints = [(10,5),(15,5),(15,10),(15,15),(10,15),(5,15),(5,10)]
        # e.g., self.m_arcindex = [(0,1,2,3),(3,4,5,6)]
        for i in range(len(self.m_arcindex)):
            # e.g., self.m_arcindex[i] = (0,1,2)
            p0 = self.m_arcpoints[self.m_arcindex[i][0]]
            p1 = self.m_arcpoints[self.m_arcindex[i][1]]
            p2 = self.m_arcpoints[self.m_arcindex[i][2]]
            p3 = self.m_arcpoints[self.m_arcindex[i][3]]
            (points,index) = cubicSpline(p0,p1,p2,p3,CURVE_SEGS)
            if self.m_solid:
                points.append(self.m_center)
                nxlast_pt = len(points)-2
                last_pt = len(points)-1
                xtra_index = [nxlast_pt,last_pt,last_pt,0]
                index = index + xtra_index
            self.m_points.append(points)
            self.m_index.append(index)

    def draw(self):
        for i in range(len(self.m_index)):
            points = self.m_points[i]
            index = self.m_index[i]
            pyglet.gl.glColor3f(self.m_color[0],self.m_color[1],self.m_color[2])
            if not self.m_solid:
                pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(len(points), pyglet.gl.GL_LINES,
                    index,
                    ('v2i',self.m_field.scale2out(tuple(chain(*points)))),
                )
            else:
                pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(len(points), pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON,
                    index,
                    ('v2i',self.m_field.scale2out(tuple(chain(*points)))),
                )
```

This is not runnable code because you are missing some constants and classes, but it might help with the theory if you are struggling with it.

Each GraphicObject, including circles and lines, was composed of arcs, each with four control points. There were made up of a list of points and an index to those points.

Similarly, but different, pyglet wanted straight line segments consisting of two points, with an index to those points. So there was a bit of translation involved.

EDIT: Earlier, I had implemented Bezier quadratic splines (essentially parabolas) which made very funny non-circular circles. The code above uses Bezier cubic splines which render true circles.